# Form validation with calabash

Tags: cucumber, calabash

I am trying validate a form with following code:

Then I should see the following fields:|New Client||Name||Age||Address||Email|

I tired:

```
Then /^I should see the following activities:$/ do |fields|
    @data = query("TextView","text")
    expected_activities.diff! @data
end
```

and

```
Then /^I should see the following activities:$/ do |expected|
    @data = query("TextView","text")
    for i in 0..expected.count-1
      if (expected[i] != @data[i])
        assert false
      end
    end
  end
```

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you want to validate in these fields?

Comment: I "tired" a lot of things to in Calabash. :)